# How to inject ObjectMapper bean in Spring Kafka JsonSerializer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-kafka

`spring-kafka` creates a `ValueSerializer` instance in the `AbstractConfig` class using a no-args constructor.

I can see that `JsonSerializer` has an `ObjectMapper` constructor which I would like to use to inject a preconfigured `ObjectMapper` bean.

The default `ObjectMapper` includes `null` values in the response which I would like to remove. I added `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion: NON_EMPTY` to my `properties.yml` but since Spring creates a default instance, this does not help me.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you configure the serializer via kafka producer properties, it is Kafka, not Spring, that creates the serializer.

You can manually add appropriately configured serializers to the producer factory, either via a constructor or setters.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#programmatic-construction

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right lines but ay have set the property incorrectly. I think you wanted

```
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null
```

Otherwise this article https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-customize-jackson-objectmapper has lots of examples to solve this issue.

Comment: According to the Jackson documentation: `Default emptiness for all types includes:
Null values and "Absent" values (see NON_ABSENT)`